# Automatonymous StateMachine how to handle NotAcceptedStateMachineException

Tags: masstransit, automatonymous

Is there any way to handle NotAcceptedStateMachineException in generic way e.g. return to client some user friendly message in request-response approach?

```
    Automatonymous.NotAcceptedStateMachineException: ExampleSagaState(8dc388ea-99b3-4d21-a3e5-915c4185ec12) Saga exception on receipt of IExampleRequest: Not accepted in state ExampleState
 ---> Automatonymous.UnhandledEventException: The ExampleEvent event is not handled during the ExampleState state for the ExampleStateMachineSaga state machine
   at Automatonymous.AutomatonymousStateMachine`1.DefaultUnhandledEventCallback(UnhandledEventContext`1 context)
   at Automatonymous.AutomatonymousStateMachine`1.UnhandledEvent(EventContext`1 context, State state)
   at Automatonymous.States.StateMachineState`1.Automatonymous.State<TInstance>.Raise[T](EventContext`2 context)
   at Automatonymous.AutomatonymousStateMachine`1.Automatonymous.StateMachine<TInstance>.RaiseEvent[T](EventContext`2 context)
   at Automatonymous.Pipeline.StateMachineSagaMessageFilter`2.Send(SagaConsumeContext`2 context, IPipe`1 next)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Automatonymous.Pipeline.StateMachineSagaMessageFilter`2.Send(SagaConsumeContext`2 context, IPipe`1 next)
   at Automatonymous.Pipeline.StateMachineSagaMessageFilter`2.Send(SagaConsumeContext`2 context, IPipe`1 next)
   at MassTransit.Saga.SendSagaPipe`2.Send(SagaRepositoryContext`2 context)
   at MassTransit.Saga.SendSagaPipe`2.Send(SagaRepositoryContext`2 context)
   at MassTransit.RedisIntegration.Contexts.RedisSagaRepositoryContextFactory`1.Send[T](ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
   at .MassTransit.RedisIntegration.Contexts.RedisSagaRepositoryContextFactory`1.Send[T](ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
   at MassTransit.Saga.Pipeline.Filters.CorrelatedSagaFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.ConsumeContext<TMessage>>.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
```

I'm using request/response to execute a state machine:

```
  IRequestClient<IExampleRequest> client = this._busControl.CreateRequestClient<IExampleMessage>(address, (MassTransit.RequestTimeout)Timeout);
  Response<IExampleResponse> response = await client.GetResponse<TRes>(message, new CancellationToken(), new MassTransit.RequestTimeout()).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I'd like to get a response of that TRes type but instead the timeout is shown.
I have tried to handle this by using OnUnhandledEvent but here i'm losing info about response type so i can't send it back.
Any ideas how to solve that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the state machine code, it's purely a guess, but the error message is clear. The state machine isn't in a state where that event is handled.

I'd suggest reviewing some [samples](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Library/blob/master/src/Library.Components/StateMachines/CheckOutStateMachine.cs) covering state machine, if possible [watching the entire season of videos](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLx8uyNNs1ri1UA_Nerr7Ej3g9nT2PxbbH) discussing that sample, state machines, and how they work in MassTransit.